# Web Audio API poor quality and other issues in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, audio, safari, web-audio-api

I'm building an mp3 player in HTML and JavaScript using the Web Audio API for my University job. The project is hosted here: http://proto.atech.tufts.edu/mixer/player.html

Everything seems to be working perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, however Safari has some major issues. Please feel free to give it a shot on your computer to see what I am talking about, but the gist is this: I got the sounds to play in Safari (which wasn't happening before due to using a SteroPanner instead of just a Panner Node), however the playback seems pretty shoddy compared to the other two browsers. Additionally none of the tracks will not mute properly, and tracking through the songs using the upper slider is very messy. I find this rather confusing since the mute functionality is based entirely around HTML elements and doesn't actually make use of the Web Audio API. One idea I have is to upload the audio into a buffer first, rather than grabbing it from an HTML5 audio element, which has been suggested by a number of tutorials. I feel this might address the poor audio playback quality, though I'm not convinced this will help with the muting problems.

Here is my github repo: https://github.com/agolin95/tts-mp3-mixer/tree/master

Has anyone else encountered strange problems like this or have any ideas what I might be missing? Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For muting/volume attach a GainNode to your source and use that rather than the HTMLMediaElement's api:

```
var gainNode = context.createGain();
source.connect(gainNode);

gainNode.gain.value = 1; // full volume
gainNode.gain.value = 0; // muted
```

And, yes, loading the sound files as buffers will work more reliably across browsers, although it will mean writing a lot more code to control audio playback. [You can see a basic example of play/pause/currentTime here](http://codepen.io/ianmcgregor/pen/EjdJZZ).

Comment: Thanks a ton imcg! The GainNode did just the trick for volume and muting functionality. I have yet to decide if I'm going to embark on the mission of loading the files into buffers (it does seem like it would require a lot more code for functionality that is currently implemented in a pretty clean and simple way), but I really appreciate the link. Definitely a great starting point! Thanks again!

Comment: I have several tracks being loaded, do you know how I can mute just one track instead of all the tracks?